# Not able to group similar records in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I am trying to group all similar records based on language. But I am not able to group in XSLT.
I am using XSL KEY function group the record in XSLT. I am trying loop and add each group records to one group.

I have the following input xml.

```
<root>
    <element name="David" language="German"></element>
    <element name="Sarah" language="German"></element>
    <element name="Isaac" language="English"></element>
    <element name="Abraham" language="German"></element>
    <element name="Jackson" language="English"></element>
    <element name="Deweher" language="English"></element>
    <element name="Jonathan" language="Hindi"></element>
    <element name="Mike" language="Hindi"></element>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:key name="lang" match="element" use="@language"></xsl:key>    
    <xsl:template match="/">    
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('lang',//element/@language)">
                <Group>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name" select=".//@language"></xsl:attribute>
                    <member><xsl:value-of select=".//@name"/></member>                
                </Group>    
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output :

```
<root>
   <Group name="German">
      <member>David</member>
      <member>Sarah</member>
      <member>Abraham</member>
   </Group>
   <Group name="English">
      <member>Isaac</member>
      <member>Jackson</member>
      <member>Deweher</member>
   </Group>
   <Group name="Hindi">
      <member>Jonathan</member>
      <member>Mike</member>
   </Group>
</root>
```

Actual Output :

```
<root>
    <Group name="German">
        <member>David</member>
    </Group>
    <Group name="German">
        <member>Sarah</member>
    </Group>
    <Group name="English">
        <member>Isaac</member>
    </Group>
    <Group name="German">
        <member>Abraham</member>
    </Group>
    <Group name="English">
        <member>Jackson</member>
    </Group>
    <Group name="English">
        <member>Deweher</member>
    </Group>
    <Group name="Hindi">
        <member>Jonathan</member>
    </Group>
    <Group name="Hindi">
        <member>Mike</member>
    </Group>
</root>
```

I am getting each records separately. 
Can someone please let me know what went wrong in the XSL. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes in your stylesheet. This should achieve the result you expect:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="lang" match="element" use="@language"></xsl:key>    

    <xsl:template match="root">    
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="element[count(. | key('lang', @language)[1]) = 1]">
                <Group name="{@language}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('lang', @language)">
                        <member><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></member>                
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Group>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first loop selects each unique language (a node-set of size 3), and creates a context for the inner loop. The inner loop iterates through each element and selects only the ones that have the same language.

*Muenchian grouping* may seem hard to grasp, but you can always apply the template shown in **[this tutorial](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)** and not have to think much. I simply applied that template to your example.

**UPDATE:** Here is a solution *without* using `for-each` loops:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="lang" match="element" use="@language"></xsl:key>    

    <xsl:template match="root">    
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="element[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('lang', @language)[1])]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element">
        <Group name="{@language}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('lang', @language)" mode="member"/>
        </Group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element" mode="member">
        <member><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></member>  
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is there any other way can we achieve by only one for loop.

Comment: Yes. You can actually get rid of all of them using templates.